# Tensorflow 1.14 no gradients provided

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to create an attack on a cnn following the example [here][1]. https://www.anishathalye.com/2017/07/25/synthesizing-adversarial-examples/

Their notebook runs on my system without any issues.

Instead of loading Inception, I want to attack my own network. For simplicity I'm training the network in the same notebook first:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, *img_shape), name='input')
y =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, total_labels), name='output')
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')

logits = conv_net(x, keep_prob, total_labels) # some standard cnn architecture is used

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=y)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

So far so good. The network is trained with

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: feature_batch, y: label_batch, keep_prob: keep_probability})
```

Now I want to create an attack by training an overlay on the image:

```
overlay = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1, *img_shape), name='Overlay')
assign_op = tf.assign(overlay, x)
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=y)
optim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(loss, var_list=[overlay])
```

My understanding is that the code above assigns the trainable Variable `overlay` to my input placeholder `x` as an input to my network, the loss is then calculated on the network predictions and the optimizer minimizes that loss. By passing `var_list` I tell the optimizer "Hey, you are training `overlay` that you cannot see explicitly."

However, this doesn't work and throws this error:

`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'Overlay:0' shape=(1, 55, 65, 1) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_3/Reshape_2:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32).`

Clearly I'm missing some step/understanding here. I don't see the source notebook doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

placeholder is not a trainable and gradients will not propagate through placeholders. If I were you, I would try next workflow: feed the data to net through a varaible at training also.

```
x = tf.placeholder(size)
x_var = tf.Variable(same_size)
assign = tf.assign(x_var, x)
logits = conv_net(x_var)
...
sess.run(assign, data)
sess.run(minimize) 
# not sure, if it would work in a single sess.run([assign, minimize], data)
```